# PP05 plastic "not dishwasher safe" but does not deform? Leaching chemicals?

Tags: plastics

It's plastic shaker cups, they came with instructions saying they are not dishwasher safe but they did not deform in the dishwasher. Does this mean it's probably unsafe to clean them using the dishwasher due to stressing the plastic, unleashing chemicals? 
Thinking of the study showing additives in PP5 plastic had estrogenic activity.
Sorry, probably really hard to give a straight forward answer to this question.

Comment: Probably far more about prolonged dishwasher exposure damages the material and makes it more likely to break.

Comment: "dishwasher safe" also depends on water temperature in dishwasher and temperature of drying cycle (if used).